# Can't insert a node in first position in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on a project with frame editing that is related to making GIF short movies. I want to add a function to change the positions of chosen frames. For example, if I want to move a frame named "3" to first position:

before:

```
1->2->3->4->5->6->NULL
```

after:

```
3->1->2->4->5->6->NULL
```

This thing works for me when I choose positions in the middle of the list or at the end but doesn't work when entering position 1.
My function:

```
void insertFrameNode(FrameNode** list, FrameNode* addNode, int pos)
{
    int i = 0; // for loops
    FrameNode* before = *list;
    FrameNode* head = *list;
    if (pos == 1)
    {
        addNode->next = head;
        *list = addNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < pos - 2; i++)
        {
            before = before->next;
        }
        addNode->next = before->next;
        before->next = addNode;
    }
    
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use a debugger :)

Comment: Also, are you sure that pos should not be 0?

Comment: The problem is that I use multiple c files so compiler not always meets my stopping mark. I will try it with 0.

Comment: It may be easier to help you if you provide a [mre] of your problem. Also, your question is then more likely to get upvoted instead of downvoted.

Comment: What does the list look like instead of 3->1->2->4->5->6->NULL?

Comment: @user253751 1->2->4->5->6->NULL because the insertion doesn't work

Comment: Turns out insertion works but the memory isn't saved after the function...

Comment: It should work. Can you show the program that creates the nodes, calls the function, and prints the result?

Answer (score -2):

head is the pointer of the list. 
Then u equate pointer of the list to add node. 
Because: `(*list)->next = head;` === `(*list)->next = addnode;` === `addnode->next = addnode`

Comment: Ok. I changed it t ` addNode->next = head;
  *list = addNode `

Comment: Now addNode will point at first and then, become the first one. Seems ok to me but still doesn't work...

Comment: if this helps, please mark the answer as correct, and I will be grateful if you put a plus to karma)

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t help. I can’t repeat this problem at home.
I think the debugger will help you)